# Smart unwrap using script

Tags: python

I am stuck. I am trying to smart unwrap objects individually using script.

I tried this code but it fails. Any help is appreciated

```
import bpy
import time

for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    if (obj.type == 'MESH'):
        bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
        print(obj.name)
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        bpy.context.object.data.uv_textures['LightMap'].active = True
        bpy.ops.uv.smart_project(angle_limit=66, island_margin = 0.02)
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

Answer (score 9):

Code Edit for 2.8x, [for 2.7x see previous revision](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/120807/revisions).

**Some Edits**

- The collection `bpy.data.objects` is **all** objects in a blend file,
  whether linked to context scene, another scene or no scene. If not in
  the context scene cannot be the context object. Use `scene.objects`
- I put the "convenience variable" `context` in test scripts, so I can
  paste later into panel or operator code where it is passed as a
  parameter to most methods, in which case better not to use path addressing from `bpy` IMO   it gets tedious reading `bpy.context.object.data.uv_foo.bar.blah`
- Add a UV map named "LightMap" if the mesh doesn't already have one.
- Blender uses [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) not degrees as the native unit of rotation.  This appears to be one of the anomalies.
- Remember to select faces to be unwrapped.

Script

```
import bpy
from math import radians

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
vl = context.view_layer
# deselect all to make sure select one at a time
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

for obj in scene.objects:
    if (obj.type == 'MESH'):
        vl.objects.active = obj
        obj.select_set(True)
        print(obj.name)
        lm =  obj.data.uv_layers.get("LightMap")
        if not lm:
            lm = obj.data.uv_layers.new(name="LightMap")
        lm.active = True
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT') # for all faces
        bpy.ops.uv.smart_project(angle_limit=66, island_margin = 0.02)
        bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
        obj.select_set(False)
```

[image]
*Resultant UVMap "LightMap" on Suzanne, using limit angle `radians(66)` interpreted as 1.152 degrees*

Related

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/172990/15543

Comment: I noticed there's now a `bpy.ops.uv.lightmap_pack()`, it seems to use more of the texture space by allocating rectangles for each face, would this be the better option to use nowadays?